# chosing the right Hall effect sensor

Tags: sensor, adc, current-measurement, component-selection, hall-effect

For a student project, I need a Hall Effect current sensor.
What I am going to do is to charge 8 rechargeable Li-Ion batteries of 3.7 volts in series with 34 volt supply and the buck circuit frequency is between 5KHz to 10KHz. My concern is finding the right hall-effect sensor for calculation of the input current to adjust the current flowing to the batteries.

The batteries are 4000-6000 mAh and I am going to use AVR to sense the output of current sensor. So, I need a sensor with 5 volt output. I am thinking about finding the right current sensor for this circuit. ACS712ELC-05B is an example however, it senses 5A which is too high for this circuit and reduces the sensitivity of my measurement. I need something in safe range but not too far. Could anybody help me with finding a better option?

Comment: How about a small resistor to measure current?

Comment: @GeorgeHerold not acceptable. btw, on resistor, both pins a floating (and with high voltage).

Comment: You could do a differential voltage measurement of the resistor with an opamp or instrument amp... 34 V is not what I would call high voltage.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold it is still high for damaging AVR.

Comment: Instrument amps have a reference output so you can put the output where ever you like... maybe an ina826? http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina826.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a sense resistor and a current sense amplifier -- this will give you far superior accuracy to either a Hall effect sensor or an instrumentation amplifier.

[The LTC6102](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC6102) is an excellent current sense amplifier. Its maximum offset voltage of \$10\rm{\mu V}\$ permits great accuracy, but it can only sense current in one direction. If you need to sense bidirectional currents and are willing to live with a bit more error, [the LT1787](http://www.linear.com/product/LT1787) is a good choice, with \$75\rm{\mu V}\$ of offset.

Comment: One direction is fine. But a few questions: can it be used alone in my case or it needs another amplifier. This image [link](http://cds.linear.com/image/7372.png) made me worried to use another amplifier. Are those extra diodes and transistors really necessary? and is it required to remove voltage offset by a potentiometer? I do not like to use any variable resistor solution.

Comment: @barej: A) The image in your link has a single amplifier. The LTC2433-1 is an Analog to Digital converter. You don't have to convert to digital if you don't want to. B) There are no diodes in the diagram, and the only transistor is *inside* the LTC6102. C) If you don't want to compensate for the offset, then you don't have to. In fact, that's why the offset is engineered to be so low: so that, under most cases, it's small enough that you won't need to correct for it.

Comment: Thank you very much. For the case of my question, how much ohm resistance do you suggest me to use?

Comment: This element is surface mounted. How to use it on prototype PCB boards?

Comment: @barej, Page 12 of the LTC6102's [datasheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/6102fe.pdf) provides guidance on selecting the sense resistor. Selection of the other components is covered in the following pages.

Comment: Thanks, How about the package, seems it does not have DIP one.

Comment: @barej, I suggest you heed the advice of others on [your other question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/166113/can-i-mount-ltc6102-on-breadboard).