# Can I mount LTC6102 on breadboard?

Tags: pcb, breadboard, pcb-assembly, packages

LTC6102 is a shunt resistor current sensor with the following datasheet:
http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/6102fe.pdf

The package Description has come on page 24. If everything is in mm, then it must not match the size of breadboard pins. Is it? If yes, how can I use it on breadboard or prototype PCB boards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not the mm that's going to cause you trouble, its the fact that this part only comes in SMD packages - which you'll have more than a little trouble stuffing into a breadboard no matter what units the package was designed in.
What you'll need is an adapter board like this one:
[image]
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/497

Comment: so is this adaptor for DFN or MS8 one?

Comment: This one is for the MS8 SSOP package

Comment: The IC is MSOP and the suggested adaptor is SSOP. Do they match?

Comment: Well ... that particular one might not be ideal ... The lead pitch matches (0.65mm) but I think the LTC's package width might be a little small to allow the leads to reach across.

Answer (score 0):

This part is a surface mount part, available in MSOP (small) and DFN (very small) surface mount packages. You can't use it on a breadboard directly - you will need to find a breakout board for that sort of package, and solder the IC onto the PCB.